# Getting checkboxes check state

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to get the check boxes' check state with the code below but ended up with the following error if the any of the checkboxes are not checked. My goal is to update the database table with the checkbox state. if checked then 1 else 0.

```
Error:
Severe:   java.lang.NullPointerException
at doPost(Controller.java:125)
```

java:

```
   String[] chkDisperse = request.getParameterValues("chkDisperse");
   int status;

            for (int i = 0; i < attId.length; i++) {
                if (chkDisperse[i] == null) {
                  //(line 25 here)
                    status = 0;
                }
               else
               {
                  status = 1;
               }
```

html:

```
<c:forEach var="AttList" items="${att}" varStatus="iter">
                <tr id="test">
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><input name="attId" type="hidden" value="${AttList.attId}" /></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" name="chkDisperse" value="${AttList.isPresentDisperse}" ${AttList.isPresentDisperse == 1 ? 'checked' : ''}></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that selected checkbox values are not being passed to the servlet. Hence you get array as null here,

`String[] chkDisperse = request.getParameterValues("chkDisperse");`.

And you end up with NPE at this line:

```
if (chkDisperse[i] == null)
```

Make sure that the checkbox are properly enclosed within the form tag. In case it is an ajax call do check the parameters being sent from the web browser console.

*Edited*

> I want to set the the status to 0 if not checked

In jsp or js file imported in jsp, try this jQuery solution:

```js
$(function() { //dom ready
  $('input[name=chkDisperse]').on('change', function() {//change event handler
    this.value = this.checked ? '1' : '0';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDisperse" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDisperse" value="1" />
```

This is plain js solution:

```js
var putState = function(input) {
  input.value = input.checked ? '1' : '0';
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDisperse" value="0" onchange='putState(this);' />
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDisperse" value="1" onchange='putState(this);' />
```

Comment: If all check boxes are checked then no error. If any one the them not checked the the error occurs, means its accepts if all check boxes are checked. I want to set the the status to 0 if not checked. please check the markup I posted.

Comment: @HafsaAbdulgafoor, it seems that some script is involved, which might be an issue submitting the checkbox

Comment: where I can apply this function? OnChange event of check box?